# How can I call a JavaScript function from an Orbeon button?

Tags: orbeon

I configured a custom button that sends Orbeon data to a service. After the [send](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes#send) is complete, I would like it to execute a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `navigate` action:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send-to-myservice.*.*">
    save
    then send(uri="http://localhost:8080/myservice")
    then success-message(message="Save Successful")
    then navigate(uri="javascript:myFunction()")
    recover error-message(message="Save Failed")
</property>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.buttons.send-to-myservice" value="Save"/>
```